# IE 11 Array shows duplicated indices

Tags: javascript, arrays, internet-explorer-11

If you log an array with one empty item and undefined(bug only happens if undefined element is included) `[, undefined]`. The result is 3 undefineds `[undefined, undefined, undefined]` but the length is still two. When you expand the output array to show more details, it shows that there are [duplicate indices/keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzTgh.png). I think this is a console error of IE, since in JavaScript, keys must be unique and if duplication keys are added, only the last one will be kept or overwritten.

My question is that what is causing this console error?

Edit: originally I wrote "I think this is a rendering error of the UI"

Comment: Huh, you're right. I just tested this in IE11 and I got `[, undefined]` results with an array with length, 2, index `0` has `undefined`, index `1` has undefined and...index `1` *again* has `undefined

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Seems to be limited to `undefined` only and only if it's the last element in a sparse array `[,,undefined]` makes a three element array but displays it as four and it doubles the last index: `2`

Comment: Am empty entry is also undefined.

Comment: Tested as well and encountered the same bizarre log. However, it's worth noting that accessing any array index in the above case will give `undefined`, just as expected. http://prntscr.com/o8vusq Sounds like an IE11 console bug rather than a real js bug to me.

Comment: @VLAZ `[,undefined,undefined]` will result in 5 `undefined`s

Comment: @nickzoum apparently so does `[undefined, , undefined]`. The item with an explicit `undefined` has a doubled index. But only in sparse arrays: `[undefined, undefined]` and `[undefined]` work correctly.

Comment: I know this isn't a JavaScript issue but IE console issue, but maybe the title of my post doesn't suggest that. Should I change my title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior of IE is not documented anywhere. But from output we can see that IE is showing the element (1) for 2 times.

So actually the length of array is 2 and there is no duplicate index number (1).

It is just that IE is showing element (1) for 2 times.

[image]